# Derby Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl

Tags: java, derby

I just installed the latest official release from Apache Derby on windows 10.12.1.1 (October 11, 2015 / SVN 1704137)

and try to install it in as Derby network server and everything goes fine with localhost but when I execute this command (java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -h myhost -p 1368) to make it accept IP other than localhost I get this error ( as you can see below every thing is fine until this command)

```
C:\>set DERBY_INSTALL=C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin


C:\>set CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbyclient.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;.


C:\>cd %derby_install%\bin


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>setNetworkClientCP.bat


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>SET DERBY_HOME=C:\Apache\DB-DER~1.1-B


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>set CLASSPATH=C:\Apache\DB-DER~1.1-B\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Apache\DB-DER~1.1-B\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\Apache\DB-DER~1.1-B/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar;C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib\derbytools.jar;.


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>java org.apache.derby.tools.ij

ij version 10.12

ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest';

ij> disconnect;

ij> exit;


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>java 
org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p 1368

Error: Could not find or load main class 
org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin>cd..


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin>cd lib


C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib>java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p 1368
```

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl

and I double check and make sure that the jar file derbynet.jar is found in lib folder and also contain the class NetworkServerControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and I just want to post it in case someone face the same problem, so 
instead of using

```
 C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib>java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -h hostname -p 1368
```

just use it this way and it's work for me

```
C:\Apache\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\lib>java -jar derbynet.jar start -p hostname -p 1368
```

Comment: Your first command should have worked, too, so long as you said '-cp derbynet.jar'. Remember that Java "jar" files in the current directory are not automatically placed in the CLASSPATH. In this way, Java is different from the Windows program launcher, which does include the current directory in the executable path. Java, however, always requires a CLASSPATH setting, either via '-cp', or '-jar', or the CLASSPATH environment variable, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarify this cause it really didn't make sense why the first command didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me:

navigate to bin folder as below and run this control command on whatever port you want to

> D:\apache_derby\db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin\bin>** .\NetworkServerControl start -p 1398

and open another cmd and give

> ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1398/mydatabase;create=true';

this will create a new database with name `mydatabase`